# Unicode in PHPMyAdmin using mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I am using `mysqli_real_escape_string` to parse characters in PHP. When I go to databases, I see:

```
&#2361;&#2366;&#2305;&#2360;&#2381;&#2344; &#2360;&#2325;&#2367;&#2344;
```

instead of:

> हाँस्न सकिन

I know these charcters represent the UNICODE of this characters. Is there a way to see the actual content without the unicode codes?

Table Collation is utf16_unicode_ci.

Comment: That's not SQL escaped. That's HTML escaped. Additionally that function does not "parse" anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are HTML character references. `mysqli_real_escape_string` doesn't do this, something else is.

That thing could be a web browser, if the data got in there from form input on a page that wasn't marked as `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`. In this case the browser has to guess what encoding the page is, and may wrongly guess it is Western European (Windows code page 1252). In that case the characters `हाँस्न सकिन` are not present in the form's encoding, so browsers panic and do a last-ditch-fallback to HTML-encoding. This is a data mangling which you can't reliably undo. You should avoid this by making sure your pages are served as UTF-8, which allows all characters.

What does your web application show on-page for this value? You should see `&#2361;&#2366;...` literally, with the ampersands and everything. If you see `हाँस्न सकिन`, that would imply you are not HTML-escaping your database contents when outputting them, which is bad news as it would likely mean you have HTML-injection (XSS) vulnerabilities.